# missing lines when running geom_line function

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I am new to R. I am working with a dataseries and want to plot multiple lines on a series where x=midpoint using ggplot. If I am working with data that contains NA values, I understand I should use `na.rm=T`. I know this kind of data is really annoying to work with, but I am curious to know if there are any quick fixes to the issues I'm having.

My dataset contains:

- a`midpoint` column (x)
- columns for `z_chlA, z_d13C,z_d15N` (y)

**NOTE: the `z_chlA` column has no NA values, but `z_d15N` and `z_d13C` have many**

The code I am working with:

```
midpoint <- proxydata$midpoint
z_chlA <- as.numeric(proxydata$z_chlA)
z_dN15 <- as.numeric(proxydata$z_d15N, na.rm=TRUE)
z_d13C <- as.numeric(proxydata$z_d13C.corrected, na.rm=TRUE)
  
ggplot(data=proxydata, x=midpoint, group=names) +
  geom_line(aes(x=midpoint, y=z_chlA)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=midpoint, y=as.numeric(z_d15N))") +
  geom_line(aes(x=midpoint, y=z_d13C))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, by= 2)) + ylim(c(-2, 3))
```

when I run it without ** na.rm=TRUE ** in the geom_line functions I get the warning message:

**Warning messages:
1: Removed 49 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
2: Removed 53 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
3: Removed 19 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).**

The code I am running makes the plot but does not plot any of the groups that have NA values in them, the line is missing in the final plot.

I tried to run it with  `na.rm=TRUE` in the first part when I define the variables `z_chlA, z_d15N, z_d13C`, and I also tried adding it to the geom_line function which did not work even though it removed the warning messages. You can see I also tried using `as.numeric()`, which did not help. **It seems like it is not plotting any of the groups that have NA values in them because my data in the chlA column has no NA's and is plotting fine**. When I use geom_point in place of geom_line, it it plots all the variables appropriately but I would like lines not points. If I use `geom_point + geom_line` it still does not plot the line.  I tried playing around with `groups=names`  in the ggplot() function but this did not work for me, I am still doing something wrong.

I can just work with a dataset that doesn't have NA values, but I am curious to know if there is a way around this otherwise.

Comment: Please share your dataframe using `dput`. If your dataframe is large, you can use `object |> head() |> dput()`.